# Jetpack Compose Recomposition every state changes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list, compose-recomposition

Here is my problem;

- When I add MyText composable in my Screen, I see all Logs (value1, value2, value3) which means it is recomposing every part of my code.
- However when I comment the MyText line, I see only value3 on Logcat

How can I fix this ? I know it is not a big problem here but just imagine  we have a scrollable Column here and we are trying to pass ScrollState.value to My Text component. Because of this situation, our list becomes so laggy.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
             Screen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen(){
    var counter by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    Log.i("RECOMPOSE","VALUE1")
    Column() {
        Text(text = "Just a text")
        Log.i("RECOMPOSE","VALUE2")
        Button(onClick = { counter = counter.plus(1) }) {
            Text(text = counter.toString())
            Log.i("RECOMPOSE","VALUE3")
        }
        MyText(counter)
    }
}
@Composable
fun MyText(counter:Int){
    Text(text = counter.toString())
}
```

**EDIT**
There is main problem, with Scrollable Column;

```
@Composable
fun Screen(){
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    Box() {
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .verticalScroll(scrollState)
            .padding(top = 50.dp)) {
            //Some Static Column Elements with images etc.
        }
        MyText(scrollStateValue = scrollState.value) //Doing some UI staff in this component
    }
}
@Composable
fun MyText(scrollStateValue:Int){
    Text(text = scrollStateValue.toString())
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My main concern is actually on scrollable components. I edit the question with my problem. When I try to scroll the page, it recompositions all elements in every scroll steps. Because of that when there are some images or complex UI elements, the scroll becomes very laggy. @PhilipDukhov

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour is totally expected.

Compose is trying to reduce number of recompositions as much as possible. When you comment out `MyText`, the only view that depends on `counter` is `Button` content, so this is the only view that needs to be recomposed.

By the same logic you shouldn't see `VALUE1` logs more than once, but the difference here is that `Column` is `inline` function, so if it content needs to be recomposed - it gets recomposed with the containing view.

Using this knowledge, you can easily prevent a view from being recomposed: you need to move part, which doesn't depends on the state, into a separate composable. The fact that it uses `scrollState` won't make it recompose, only reading state value will trigger recomposition.

```
@Composable
fun Screen(){
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    Box() {
        YourColumn(scrollState)
        MyText(scrollStateValue = scrollState.value) //Doing some UI staff in this component
    }
}

@Composable
fun YourColumn(scrollState: ScrollState){
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
        .padding(top = 50.dp)) {
        //Some Static Column Elements with images etc.
    }
}
```